# Redshift : Split the comma separated values to different rows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table which has one column with values separated by commas

```
Table_A
State       City
Colorado    Denver
Texas       Dallas, Houston, Austin
Arizona     Phoenix, Flagstaff

Expected_Result
Table_A
State       City
Colorado    Denver
Texas       Dallas
Texas       Houston
Texas       Austin
Arizona     Phoenix
Arizona     Flagstaff
```

There are easier ways to do it in SQL but can't find anything similar in Redshift. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use [split_to_array](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/split_to_array.html) function to change the comma separated column into an array, then you can do with a [join](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/nested-data-use-cases.html#joining-redshift-data).

```
with array_data as (
  select State, split_to_array(City , ',') as city
  from Table_A
)
SELECT t.state, cities as city
FROM array_data AS t
    LEFT JOIN t.city AS cities ON TRUE;
```