# Comma separated values into rows in Redshift

Tags: sql, arrays, amazon-redshift

I am using the following code to convert comma separated values into rows:

```
CREATE table a_table (
    id int,
    data varchar
); 

INSERT INTO a_table 
    VALUES (1, 'Apple,Orance'),
        (2, 'Apple,Grapes'),
        (3, 'Juice,Apple,Cucumber');
        
SELECT * FROM a_table;
        
        
SELECT id, unnest(string_to_array(data,','))
FROM a_table;

SELECT
    *,
    unnest(string_to_array(data, ','))
FROM
    a_table;
```

But I get the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "unnest"
LINE 1: SELECT id, unnest(string_to_array(data,','))
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have looked at multiple forums and everything pointed me in the direction of using `unnest` and `string_to_array()`.

Comment: Your code works fine in Postgres, back to version 9.3 : https://dbfiddle.uk/-Kob7Mm0. Are you running Redshift or Postgres - and which version? These are two different database systems.

Comment: You just need to add an alias to the star... change it to: `select a.*, .... from a_table a;`

Comment: @GMB I am using Redshift. Version is `PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.49780`.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I edited my query to `SELECT
 a_table.*,
 unnest(string_to_array(a_table.data, ','))
FROM
 a_table;` and I still get the same error.

Comment: @JorgeCampos `SELECT
 a.*,
 unnest(string_to_array(a.data, ','))
FROM
 a_table a;` also gives me the same error.

Comment: yeah, not sure why it is not working with redshift... it does work in postgres, sorry.

Comment: is unnest function available on redshift? I just noticed that the error is on the query you used it first

Comment: `string_to_array` is not a thing in Redshift. I am confused which database you do use.

Comment: Yeah, looks like these functions aren't available in Redshift. I am using Redshift, so I'll have to figure something else out.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75343219/redshift-split-the-comma-separated-values-to-different-rows? I don't have a Redshift database at hand so I can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Redshift is not Postgres. By a long shot.

Table functions like `unnest()` are not supported in Redshift at all. Neither are `LATERAL` joins (which would come in handy) or even the function `string_to_array()` See:

- [Unsupported PostgreSQL features](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html)

But there is the similar function [`split_to_array()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/split_to_array.html).
And recently, Redshift added functionality to unnest arrays too. [The manual:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html#unnest)

> To unnest queries, Amazon Redshift uses the PartiQL syntax to iterate
> over SUPER arrays. It does this by navigating the array using the FROM
> clause of a query.

So this should do the job:

```sql
SELECT id, datum
FROM  (
   SELECT id, split_to_array(data, ',') AS data_arr
   FROM   a_table
   ) a, a.data_arr AS datum;
```