# Count occurrences of Strings from Array column

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have an SQL table with column name `fruits_option` which is an array type like below:
[image]

Now I want to count the occurrences of each fruits like below:
[image]

I am using PostgreSQL 8.0.2. I even tried below query:

```
SELECT
    category,
    COUNT(*) AS category_count
FROM
    your_table,
    JSON_TABLE(
        categories_column,
        '$[*]' COLUMNS (
            category VARCHAR(255) PATH '$'
        )
    ) AS jt
GROUP BY
    category;
```

but this failed with error as

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "COLUMNS"

Comment: Please run this query: `SELECT VERSION();` I know you wrote that you are using MySQL 8.0, but apparently you are not. You might be using a MySQL 8.0 _client_ connected to a MySQL Server that does not support `JSON_TABLE()`. The query I showed will confirm it.

Comment: What is `category` and `your_table`? Your screenshots don't seem to show either.

Comment: @esqew your_table is the table name and categories column in this case is fruits_options. Category is created by identifying new fruits in the array column if you see the SQL statement

Comment: @BillKarwin PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.60353
I got above o/p on running SELECT VERSION()

Comment: You’re not running MySQL, you’re quite clearly running PostgreSQL. How did you reach that conclusion…?

Comment: @esqew As already commented, I have run SELECT VERSION() and pasted the output and then reached to conclusion that its a PostgreSQL. whats there to clarify sorry I dont understand you

Comment: Firstly - PostgreSQL is not MySQL - my original question was regarding how you got to the conclusion that you were running the latter and not the former. Secondly, PostgreSQL 8.0.2 has been end-of-life and has not received any updates **in over 13 years** (as of this writing). You really should be on a much, much, MUCH later version if you care at all about the security of your data. Lastly - PostgreSQL (any version) has no function called `JSON_TABLE`. Can you provide a source from which you're seeing an assertion to the contrary?

Comment: PostgreSQL didn't even have any JSON parsing functions to begin with [until version 9.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @esqew Amazon Redshift is **not** PostgreSQL. Far from it. Was just derived from Postgres a long time ago. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html That's why, sadly, `unnest()` is not supportet. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76285109/939860

Comment: Thanks @esqew. have gone through the redshift notes and found the solution.

Comment: @souravkumar Looks like you wanted to address me in your last comment. 